# Itunes Store error uploading app with Xcode6 GM

Tags: app-store, xcode6, itunes-store

Trying to upload (validating) app to App Store with XCode 6 GM and I am getting this error message. Is it possible to upload with xcode 6 gm? What am I missing?

[image: Error message]

**Upddate:**
I still have the same error when uploading with XCode 6 GM, but I noticed that it is possible to upload with Application Uploader.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload xCode6 apps before the official release of xCode 6 and iOS8. But you can do something like that:

- Finish your app in xCode 5 and 6, upload it from 5 and after the official iOS8 release upload (or a newer version) the xCode 6 version. In this case you don't have to wait for iOS8 and your app can be in the app store asap.

Comment: Ok I know that its not possible to upload with the beta versions. But this is the GM version of XCode 6.